# Sorting an XML file based on node value

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xslt, xslt-2.0

I was trying to compare two XML files which have same content but on different lines at times. To overcome this, I was trying to sort the XMLs on one of the child nodes (which usually differs in position in both files).

Here is my sample XML file

```
<Report>
<rptName>Sample</rptName>
<reportNameGrp>
<grpName>AggrDataSet</grpName>
<RC>
<rptSubHdr>
<membLglNam>Registered Customer 103</membLglNam>
<membId>RC103</membId>
<relCM>CM022</relCM>
</rptSubHdr>
</RC>
<RC>
<rptSubHdr>
<membLglNam>Registered Customer 055</membLglNam>
<membId>RC055</membId>
<relCM>CM022</relCM>
</rptSubHdr>
</RC>
<RC>
<rptSubHdr>
<membLglNam>Registered Customer 047</membLglNam>
<membId>RC047</membId>
<relCM>CM022</relCM>
</rptSubHdr>
</RC>
<RC>
<rptSubHdr>
<membLglNam>Registered Customer 015</membLglNam>
<membId>RC015</membId>
<relCM>CM022</relCM>
</rptSubHdr>
</RC>
<RC>
<rptSubHdr>
<membLglNam>Registered Customer 024</membLglNam>
<membId>RC024</membId>
<relCM>CM022</relCM>
</rptSubHdr>
</RC>
</reportNameGrp>
</Report>
```

I am trying to sort based on `<membId>` node for `<RC>` parent node. Whatever method I try, my document fails to sort. I tried using XSLT, but sorting doesn't work. I even tried writing a python script but it fails to sort.

Here is my python script -

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

filename, tag = sys.argv[1:]

doc = etree.parse(filename, etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))
root = doc.getroot()
root[:] = sorted(root, key=lambda el: el.findtext(tag))
print etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
```

I execute `python test.py 2.xml membId` to run the script (please note that 2.xml is file name for input xml and membId is the tag I was looking for).

I will really appreciate any help in where I am going wrong. I am just starting with Python, so I might have made some pretty obvious mistake. A python script or XSLT solution (either) will work for me!

Comment: **1.** "*I tried using XSLT, but sorting doesn't work.*" Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of writing your code for you from scratch. -- **2.** While you're at it, post also the expected output, as "*sort based on <membId> node for <RC> parent node*" is a rather cryptic requirement.  -- **3.** Why is your question tagged `XSLT 2.0`? Are you in fact using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Python's lxml only supports XSLT 1.0, using the libxslt processor.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I will post another question just with XSLT seeking help  on that part. And yes, I was using XSLT2.0 and that is why I tagged it so.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following XSLT script with Python's `lxml` integration. Also, you attempt to run a dynamic command line process. Unfortunately, the XSLT will structurally change depending on what specific node you intend to sort. Below will specifically sort `<membId>` in ascending order:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Sort MembId under RC/rptSubHdr -->
  <xsl:template match="reportNameGrp">
    <xsl:copy>      
        <xsl:copy-of select="grpName"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RC">          
            <xsl:sort select="rptSubHdr/membId" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

// LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
dom = et.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = et.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

// TRANSFORM
transform = et.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

// SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(newdom)
```

Comment: This will discard the `grpName` element.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me give a direction but not actually solve the issue. I think I will post another question only with the XSLT I am having issue with so that I can get help with that.

Comment: What is the issue? Your question title and text mentions sorting XML value by node which this answer does. Please describe in detail with desired output. Also, XSLT 1.0 can even parse from other files using [document()](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp).